# Jquery: Toggle text colors with checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to be able to set the color of a text passage when a certain checkbox is checked. I've tried stuff like

```
$('#CheckboxForMakingStuffBlue:checked').( function() {
   $('span.externalNarrative').css("color","blue");
   });
```

but I can't get anything to work. Is there another function I should be using, or an "if" statment of some sort? I'm very very new to jquery, and to stuff like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the link : http://jsfiddle.net/developeryamhi/BeLVq/3/ for detailed help

Comment: That's so awesome, thanks. That's exactly what I was trying to do. And what a neat website, too.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not correct, should be like this:

```
$('#CheckboxForMakingStuffBlue').click(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked')){
     $('span.externalNarrative').css("color","blue");
  }
  else {
     $('span.externalNarrative').css("color","black");
  }
});
```

Also make sure to wrap your code in ready handler:

```
$(function(){
    $('#CheckboxForMakingStuffBlue').click(function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked')){
         $('span.externalNarrative').css("color","blue");
      }
     else {
         $('span.externalNarrative').css("color","black");
     }
    });
});
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. Is there a way to remove the color when the box is unchecked, like if ($(this).isnot(':checked')?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `radio` input instead as you will only have one color at a time. **See working example here:**

http://jsfiddle.net/9VwuR/1/

```
$(":radio").click(function(){
    $("p").css({color: $(this).val() });
});
```

The key is that you need to attach an `event` to the `element`, in this case is `click`, because you want this color change to happen when the user selects an input.

Check some other jQuery events here: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a trigger: http://jsfiddle.net/LekisS/RFFHA/

Answer (score 0):

you shoud use

```
    $('#CheckboxForMakingStuffBlue').change(function(){ 

  // some conditions here
      $('span.externalNarrative').css("color","blue");
       });

    })
```

Something like this